# How to only style the text inside a p tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress, visual-composer

```
<div>
<p style="font-size=40px;">
<b>Hello there, welcome</b>
<br/>
To this website
</p>
<p>Some other text</p>
```

How do I only grab the text inside the first p tag ("To This Website")?
I can't give it an class or ID, because it's done with visual composer in wordpress and I can also not style it in wordpress, but I only need to style that part.

Comment: do you have live website? so we can inspect, you can use `:first-child` selector.

Comment: only first p tag color change ?? or all p tag color chage

Comment: A bit of JavaScript to put the text node in a span is not an option? Then you can style the whole `p` and reverse the style for `p b`. For instance `p {text-decoration: underline} p b {text-decoration: none}`

Comment: you can edit the visual composer in wordpress and add a `style` on it.

Comment: I tried :first-child, and I can not edit it in visual composer for some reason I do not understand.

Comment: better if you give us the link of your wordpress, so we can check it,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGpvxE

**Snippet Example:**

```css
    p:first-child {
      color: red !important; /** Use important only in very rare situations **/
    }
    
    p b {
      color: initial;
    }
```

```html
 <div>
    <p>
    <b>Hello there, welcome</b>
    <br/>
    To this website
    </p>
    <p>Some other text</p>
    </div>
```

##### *Edit*:

To override the inline styling, you can use `!important` in your CSS.

Comment: Something like this would normally work. I tried this but I do not understand why it won't work. I edited my question though. Wordpress puts a style element in the p that iI cannot edit.

Comment: You can override the style attributes with the !important flag behind the rule. (font-size:20px !important;)